# make hidden input field considered 'valid'

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Why is a hidden input not considerd 'valid' by the jquery selector and what can I do about that (i.e. to make it valid).

```js
console.log($("#a").is(":valid")); // true
console.log($("#b").is(":valid")); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="a" type="text" value="abc">
<input id="b" type="hidden" value="def">
```

Comment: because :valid is a CSS property with certain rules. It's not validating the input as you might expect. It only affects non hidden inputs, since hidden inputs can't be changed by the user and can therefore not be "not valid"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden#Validation):

> Hidden inputs don't participate in constraint validation; they have no
>   real value to be constrained.

And as such will not receive any `valid` or `invalid` pseudoclasses. A couple of options come to mind, either filter the collection to exclude `hidden` inputs or use this check as a workaround:

```
$("#b").is(":not(:invalid)");
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log($("#a").is(":valid")); // true
console.log($("#b").is(":valid")); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="a" type="text" value="abc">
<input id="b" type="text" style="display:none" value="def">
```

**Change type from hidden to text, then use CSS to change the display property to none**